# django template print out by filter id value

Tags: python, django

I want to print value by `id` in database,And don't know which keywords to find in Google.
in my `views.py`, I send  `transen = TransEn.objects.all()` to `template`

and this will print all datas from database:

```
{% for words in transen %}
{{words.words|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

But I want to print by the value of the id  Like:
(Because they are words in English for translating website) 
I don't know how to write this in template, please guide me, Thank you very much.

```
<div><span>  TransEn.objects.filter(id='2') </span></div> 
<div> TransEn.objects.filter(id='3') </div>
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I have found a method:

I can use `if` tag, but are there another ideas??

```
<div>
    {% for words in transen %}
        {% if words.id == 2 %}
             {{ words.words|safe }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<div>
    {% for words in transen %}
        {% if words.id == 3 %}
            {{ words.words|safe }}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access each item in the QuerySet individually, by index, you should cast it to a list first. You should change your `views.py` to:

```
transen = list(TransEn.objects.all())
```

And then in your template you can access them by index like so:

```
<div><span> {{ transen.1.words }} </span></div> 
<div> {{ transen.2.words }} </div>
```

A warning from the [Django docuemtnation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) about casting a QuerySet to a list:

> Be warned, though, that this could have a large memory overhead, because Django will load each element of the list into memory. In contrast, iterating over a QuerySet will take advantage of your database to load data and instantiate objects only as you need them.

Comment: I try this,seems like it can't get by id value saved in database. so if my id start by 2 or lacking number.It will not get the right value